# Accessing JSON elements with Python and Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a few questions about JSON in Pandas! I have gotten the data loaded into a dataframe and can search effectively with the query code below. Three questions I have:

1. How can I get the individual pieces of 'coord' (i.e. 'coord.lon')
2. How do I assign specific columns to variables in the code? (i.e. state = df.loc[df['name'] == city, ['state'])?
3. How can I add additional search terms? (i.e. df['name'] == city AND df['state'] == state)

Here is the code I have so far to pull the records I need:

`query = df.loc[df['name'] == city, ['id', 'name', 'state', 'coord']]`

Here is a sample of the JSON response I am trying to search:

```json
{
    "id": 5074329,
    "name": "Oakland",
    "state": "NE",
    "country": "US",
    "coord": {
        "lon": -96.466972,
        "lat": 41.835831
    }
},
{
    "id": 5074472,
    "name": "Omaha",
    "state": "NE",
    "country": "US",
    "coord": {
        "lon": -95.93779,
        "lat": 41.25861
    }
}
```

As always, THANKS!!

edit: Here is a picture of a couple rows of the dataframe:

```
url = 'http://bulk.openweathermap.org/sample/city.list.json.gz'

df = pd.read_json(url)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the dataframe you are generating from the json file?

Comment: @JMA - Thanks for getting back to me. I have added a screenshot above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the dataframe like this:

```
        id     name state country                                  coord
0  5074329  Oakland    NE      US  {'lon': -96.466972, 'lat': 41.835831}
1  5074472    Omaha    NE      US    {'lon': -95.93779, 'lat': 41.25861}
```

1. To access `lon` you can use the `str` method:

```
df['lon'] = df.coord.str['lon'] 

#output
        id     name state country                                  coord  \
0  5074329  Oakland    NE      US  {'lon': -96.466972, 'lat': 41.835831}   
1  5074472    Omaha    NE      US    {'lon': -95.93779, 'lat': 41.25861}   

         lon  
0 -96.466972  
1 -95.937790
```

2. I guess you wanna do [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html) here:

```
city =  'Omaha'
state = df.loc[df['name'] == city]['state']
```

The above code will return the `pandas series`. If you want only the 1st value use `iloc`:

```
city =  'Omaha'
state = df.loc[df['name'] == city]['state'].iloc[0]

# output
'NE'
```

3. This is quite similar to the 2nd part:

```
city = 'Omaha'
state = 'NE'
suset_df = df.loc[(df['name'] == city) & (df['state'] == state)]

# OUTPUT
        id   name state country                                coord       lon
1  5074472  Omaha    NE      US  {'lon': -95.93779, 'lat': 41.25861} -95.93779
```